# Add html tags with custom text on facebook sharer link. Link https://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?quote=CUSTOM_TEXT

Tags: facebook, facebook-sharer

I want to use html tags like `<a></a>`, `<br>` tags, in custom text like
`$text = Hello<br>World`

https://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?u=$current_url&t=title&quote=$text

Comment: Your url seems to be invalid and your question is not quite clear.

Comment: HTML is not possible. You can only specify plain text as the suggested quote. If you need a line break, you can achieve that by using `%0a`.